# How do I create a spec which verifies Pundit rejects users that are not logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, pundit

I'm using the Pundit gem for authorization on my closed system Ruby on Rails application (using Rails 4.1.5 and Rspec 3.0)

I've configured my application policy to raise an exception when the user is not defined as recommended in the Pundit documentation:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "must be logged in" unless user
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end
end
```

How can I write a spec which verifies that each Pundit policy rejects a nil user?

I made the following attempt:

```
RSpec.describe PostPolicy do
  it "should raise an exception when users aren't logged in" do
    expect(AccountFolderPolicy.new(nil, record)).to  raise_error(Pundit::NotAuthorizedError)
  end
end
```

But it errors out with

```
 Failure/Error: expect(PostPolicy.new(nil, record)).to raise_error(Pundit::NotAuthorizedError)
 Pundit::NotAuthorizedError:
   must be logged in
```

Any suggestions on how to properly test this?

Comment: [expecting errors should work with lambda or block `expect { ... }.to raise_error`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#expecting-errors) instead  `expect( ... ).to  raise_error()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RSpec cannot catch the error in the background unless you [use the `raise_error` matcher with the block form of `expect`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-1/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher):

```
RSpec.describe PostPolicy do
  it "should raise an exception when users aren't logged in" do
    expect do
      AccountFolderPolicy.new(nil, record)
    end.to  raise_error(Pundit::NotAuthorizedError)
  end
end
```

Alternatively

```
RSpec.describe PostPolicy do
  it "should raise an exception when users aren't logged in" do
    expect { AccountFolderPolicy.new(nil, record) }.to  raise_error(Pundit::NotAuthorizedError)
  end
end
```

Comment: as i saying in comment. +1 for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't even see your comment!